# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error in my code and I don't know how to solve it my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once"connect_to_mysql.php";

$db_host = "localhost";
// Place the username for the MySQL database here
$db_username = "root"; 
// Place the password for the MySQL database here
$db_pass = "****"; 
// Place the name for the MySQL database here
$db_name = "mrmagicadam";

// Run the actual connection here 
$myConnection= mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("mrmagicadam") or die ("no database");        
$sqlCommand="SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages ORDER BY pageorder ASC";
$query=mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$menuDisplay="";


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $pid=$row["id"];
    $linklabel=$row["linklabel"];
$menuDisplay='<a href="index.php?pid=' .$pid . '">' .$linklabel. '</a><br/>';
}
mysqli_free_result($query);

?>
```

and this is error:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\limitless\connect_to_mysql.php on line 17

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tip: use the search feature to search for the exact error message you're getting. I can guarantee you this question has been answered many times before.

Answer (score 28):

You are mixing [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) and [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extensions, which will not work.

You need to use

```
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($myConnection, "mrmagicadam") or die ("no database");
```

`mysqli` has many improvements over the original `mysql` extension, so it is recommended that you use `mysqli`.

Comment: Or make the jump to PDO which offers many features MySQLi does not and makes it a lot easier to avoid SQL Injection. Plus it lets you do object mapping (in case you don't want to use an ORM but like the idea)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Answer (score 7):

You are using improper syntax. If you read the docs [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) you will find that it needs two parameter.

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

`mysql $link` generally means, the resource object of the established mysqli connection to query the database.

So there are two ways of solving this problem

mysqli_query();

```
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "mrmagicadam") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
$sqlCommand="SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages ORDER BY pageorder ASC";
$query=mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($myConnection));
```

Or, Using `mysql_query()` (This is now obselete)

```
$myConnection= mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("mrmagicadam") or die ("no database");        
$sqlCommand="SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages ORDER BY pageorder ASC";
$query=mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
```

As pointed out in the comments, be aware of using die to just get the error. It might inadvertently give the viewer some sensitive information .

Comment: In your second example you are mixing MySQL and MySQLi libraries. I've heard that works in some cases, but I imagine it is wise to stick to just one?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)