# How to get multiple rows from a database request

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I have so far. It calls to the database and receives one comment and all of the values that go with it, but I want to get multiple comments with the same id. How do I set up a array to get the multiple comments?

```
function get_comment_by_id($lake_id) {

        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM comments ";
        $query .= "WHERE lakeId=" . $lake_id ." ";
        //$query .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        confirm_query($result_set);

        // REMEMBER:
        // if no rows are returned, fetch_array will return false
        if ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
            return $comment;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to put it in a while loop. instead of

```
if ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    return $comment;
} else {
    return NULL;
}
```

do

```
$rows = array();
while($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
    $rows[] = $comment;

return $rows;
```

and you also need to use `mysqli_*` functions since the `mysql_*` functions are deprecacted.

In the calling function you should check for an empty array instead of a null value

Comment: no problem, if it answers you question just hit the check mark to select it

Comment: now I have this error: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160664/mysqli-query-warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli

Comment: you need to be consistent with your use of mysqli functions